# Can a 3.5mm headphone splitter be used to join two inputs into one output?

Tags: audio, splitter

I want to be able to connect up my PC and iPod to the same speakers at the same time using a 3.5mm jack (very fiddly at the moment) - I have seen this [Speaker and Headphones Splitter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-Speaker-Headphones-Splitter-White/dp/B000CI3480/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1277128083&sr=8-9) and wondered if it could be used for this purpose. Would it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend that. Any time you join the outputs of two or more amplifiers (and a soundcard is just that, if weak), you risk damaging one or the other.

Comment: How would this damage stuff exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You could [build your own solution](http://www.instructables.com/id/Altoids-Tin-18-Stereo-Mixer/) if you are looking for a fun project for the weekend.

Answer (score 3):

The other way is also possible, use for example 2 inputs and 1 output (with a switch):
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Construct-a-35mm-Switch-diy/

Please, check the picture for my own result of this project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose between two inputs, then you need some sort of switch to turn one input off and the other one on.

I've not come across any switches that have 3.5mm inputs and outputs, but a search of some where like Maplins might yield some results.

Comment: I turned to this because I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: I'm looking to do something simular - PS3 + xbox 360 + any other random inputs (PC most likely) -> speakers.

Seems so far I need a desktop mixer + loads of 3.5mm to RCA Phono plug adapters. :<

Is there some reason other than "no one else needs it" that there isn't seemingly any products offering this?

Currently I have the ps3 and 360 on seperate line-in's on my sound card, and control it via my PC, however that means when the PC is off no sound, and alsa-mixer is kinda rubbish too!