# Analog RCA splitter

Tags: audio, analog, rca

We just got an Airport Express to use AirPlay on our stereos. Now our most 'advanced' stereo system we want to connect has a single analog RCA input for audio. This is of course bullshit.

The stereo is also connected to the television through analog RCA connectors, so it's already 'filled up'.

I know of the existence of aux-splitters, so **are there also Analog RCA-splitters of some sort, preferrably without the loss of quality?** Since it's for input to the stereo and not output, I'm hoping the quality remains.

I've searched around, but haven't found anything that seems to have the connections I need.

So in short - does something exist to go from 1 Analog RCA to 2 Analog RCA's? So I have one connection (which consists of 2 ports - the right audio & left audio), yet I need to connect 4 cables (2 right & 2 left)

**Edit:**
Just an idea - to avoid having multiple mixers. Let the two audio outputs go to a male auxiliary. Then, use something like [this](http://www.topiphoneshop.com/image/cache/data/fdf425ada32fdafeca98b180090a5f65-700x700.jpg) to get it to a single auxiliary, and finally a female-aux to Analog RCA [like this](http://image0.buyincoins.com/bicv2/product/s0/show/3.5mm-female-2rca-adapter.jpg) and this goes into the input of the stereo.

Would this work, or are these way too many connections? The output from the Airport Express is already AUX, and the one from the television can be auxiliary or Analog RCA depending on whatever delivers better performance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thought it was clear, edited the answer to clarify, @wallyk

Comment: By "single analog RCA input" do you mean that there is just one port? If so, that probably means it is mono. You'll probably need a converter to go from stereo to mono so you don't lose any portion of the signal and then you'll probably want an RCA switch to interconnect everything (http://www.cablewholesale.com/products/audio-video-products/audio-video-switch/product-40r4-13400.php?utm_source=GoogleShopping&utm_medium=organic&zmam=54972865&zmas=1&zmac=1&zmap=136&gclid=CJutwNjR5rgCFZE7MgodYH0A7w)

Comment: @MaQleod : no two ports! Edited my answer to clarify it a bit. I have 2 ports, yet need to connect 4 cables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're saying there is only one RCA phono stereo input on your system, and you want to be able to connect two different sources (TV and Airport Express)...

You'll need a an audio switching unit such as [here](http://www.audiovisualonline.co.uk/product/1514/rca-phono-audio-switching-unit-3-way/). I can't recommend one device from another. There will be some loss of audio quality and depending on your equipment, you may or may not notice this.

If there is a digital input on your stereo system, you might consider using this.

EDIT: After reading conflicting opinions on the option of combining two different sources using x2 RCA Y-splitters (or 3.5mm jack equivalents), I found a lengthy discussion on it [here](http://www.avsforum.com/t/781811/left-and-right-rca-jacks-into-a-single-mono-rca-jack). It does seem that a lot of people do it though Y spitters are typically used for splitting the signal, not combining/merging and it is not safe practice.

EDIT: There's a discussion on using an in-line resistor to negate the potential risk of overloading the outputs [here](http://www.avsforum.com/t/1202569/combine-via-y-cables-two-rca-outputs-into-one-input-okay) and [here](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/general-electronics-chat/26488-rca-y-splitter-%3D-joiner.html) if you fancied a DIY project.

Comment: I'm guessing this requires manual selection of the input, hence the knob? I'd prefer it to be automatic, otherwise it'd be easier to just plug in the other cables when wanting to change channel.

Comment: Search for 'phono switching remote' or something similar, but it won't be cheap. Digital input?

Comment: Mmm a remote for someting this simple seems so overkill... There seems to be no input other than analog RCA :/

Comment: [Like this](http://www.sonance.com/products/accessories/detail/20). The cost is going to be prohibitive and possibly in excess of the stereo. Please mark this as answered if you have no more questions.

Comment: All the reasonably priced automatic switches I can find are based on a video signal.

Comment: Could the method I edited in my question be good as well?

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/154997/can-a-3-5mm-headphone-splitter-be-used-to-join-two-inputs-into-one-output)

Answer (score 2):

**Just buy (2) "2F to 1M RCA splitter" (google it).**  You don't NEED a switch.  A switch is nice if you want to  be able to not have to turn the sound down on the TV when you want to listen to the Air Play.

As to sound quality, unless your have system that you have cost you 2K$ or more and you have a listening environment to support it, you probably cannot tell the difference from 4$ connectors and 40$ connectors.  Possibly on really bad ones you could tell, but unlikely you would get connectors that bad.  Connectors that bad aren't cheap, there defective.

The mixers allow you to adjust the volume of each input relative to each other while they are being played at the same time.  You don't NEED that either unless you want it.

Comment: Since our system was rather expensive, with speakers made of some special wood for better sound (I don't know the specifics), I think we're going to go for a solution that will guarantee good quality. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you have a 30K system, it will only be as good as the weakest link.  I can't imagine the Airport Express putting out audiophile sound quality for $100.  And if your stereo is filled up with a single input, again, sounds like that is not an audiophile receiver; I could be wrong though.

Comment: @arbitter - Damon's scheme will work.  You do have to turn the volume down on (or turn off) the unused source, and there will be some loss of volume and possibly quality because part of the signal will be sucked off by the other device.  But the only other option is a switch.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Did you read my edit and the link about issues with combining two sources? I'm not sure ensuring the other output is powered off is a risk worth taking for the sake of the purchase of a switching unit.

Comment: @archery1234 Admittedly, the more money you spend, the more issues you avert.  Simply combining the signals is not inherently going to cause damage.  Even your link shows that.  Turning both input sources at the same time to max volume might.  Buying a manual switch is more expensive and offers the isolation between inputs.  Buying an auto switch cost even more and makes it easier and offers isolation.  Putting a resistor inline allows a y-splitter with a level of isolation without a switch.  Point is, there is more than 1 way to skin a cat, each with trade-offs.

Comment: @Damon, The point for the OP is that it might, there are occasions when it has (and more when it hasn't no doubt). It's not a risk I'd be willing to take for the sake of few £/$s. The link for a manual switch was the first I came across, there are [cheaper options](http://www.kenable.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=2216&gclid=CJ-steGX6rgCFQTMtAodz14Ajw).

Comment: The costs are for my parents, it's their system. If there would have been multiple inputs in the system, we would also need to change channels for one or the other, so something with a switch or knobs is good as well, though I don't think I'm going to opt for something with a remote, since that's a remote for one single function. I'm going to go to a local dealer (where we bought the stereo), and see what the best solution is they have.

Comment: @archery1234 - The standard low-level RCA signal (not a speaker signal) is a relatively high-impedance one.  While there is a theoretical danger of damage, it's not significant in practice.  Combining speaker outputs, on the other hand, *would* risk damage.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, aren't line level outputs low impedance sources? Shorting them might be a theoretical risk (I'm not convinced it is only theory) but it can't do the sound quality any favours. Most sources I looked at yesterday had this down as a big no no.

Comment: I'd love to see the schematic showing that combing input sources shorts something.  Might learn something from that schematic.  But I can't see how it is shorting any thing without a schematic showing me..  I imagine most damage would be done via extra voltage if line level was combine with low level or extra current from combining.  But if you stay within limits of the circuitry (voltage and current) things would be ok.  This means, turn up the volume of the amp, not the input.

Comment: But if it is for someone else asking for help (parents in this case), things should more or less be fool proof meaning switch.

Comment: @Damon Is [this](http://www.rane.com/note109.html) or [this](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/linesum.html) any help?

Comment: There are several different line-level standards.  The 3-pin XLR style is between 150 and 600 ohms, 1/4", 1/8", et al are somewhere below 1000, IIRC.  Phono/RCA (when used for audio) is generally over 1000 ohms.  (RCA plugs, when used for video, OTOH, are generally 50 ohms.)  There is some variation depending on whether you're talking about "mic", "low-level", or "high-level", and, of course, loudspeaker connections are something else entirely.

Comment: This is intense..LOL  Probably should be moved to a chat, but I got to much work to do to participate :).  Fun to look into though!

Comment: @DanielRHicks, you're better versed on this than me. I still stand by my answer as being the most relevant (in this particular case).

Comment: And keep in mind that consumer electronic devices are going to be protected against damage due to accidentally shorting the outputs.  In particular, RCA plugs are so easily shorted that they *must* be well-protected.  The protection is accomplished essentially by placing some resistance in series with the center pin (this resistance representing the lion's share of the "impedance").  Only XLR connected signals (which are not "consumer") would be at (slight) risk of damage from shorting (and the design of the XLR connector makes shorting very unlikely).

Comment: The input source may be protected against accidental shorting but if you look at the links above you'll note the typical RCA plugs do not offer this. There a instructions on using the in line resistors you mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @archery1234 - Any reasonably well-designed "consumer" device that provides a line level output will protect that output against shorts, *especially* if the output is phono/RCA.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Apologies, input source is ambiguous, it should be the line level outputs as you stated. If you're correct then why all the hoo-hah in my links to the audiophile websites. If you have a link suggesting that most consumer devices protect the outputs against the aforementioned shorts then I'd like to see that. I'd take your word for it but this discourse has gone on too long for that.

Comment: @archery How can the cables exist to splice two outputs into one input and STILL be used by thousands, if not millions of people if this usually ruins things.  The answer is it doesn't hurt things in general.  But if you wanted to ruin a receiver by doing this, you could easily set splice in two outputs, turn the volume to max on both, and play it that way until things broke.  This is not what people usually do and the reason why it works.

Comment: @archery Also, you keep mentioning your links showing a short, or showing lack or protection circuitry and I must add that your links begin where the output circuitry of the receiver ends; they do not show any circuitry behind the outputs (in the receiver) which means we all are in the dark about how the output circuitry is built meaning everything said is based on a guess of what we think the output circuitry is.  Without this information, some inferences have to be made based on real world experience; does it work for people or not; the answer is it USUALLY does.  Sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think the name of the thing you are looking for is "distribution amp"</strike>

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005N0CRT4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005N0CRT4) is an example but it does video as well as audio.

EDIT: Noticed you want to "combine" two inputs (not outputs) into one.  You need a mixer.  Something like this: http://www.fullcompass.com/product/297476.html?utm_source=googleps&utm_medium=shopping&utm_campaign=googleps&gclid=CPy1-cnS5rgCFevm7AodOHYANA

If you know someone who plays music in live settings they could probably be a good source of information.

Comment: Yeah I want to combine two inputs so that we don't need to always plug in another cable depending on the source we want to hear. The mixer you linked does seem a bit weird though... It has 4 in and only one out? And does it require you to change the buttons if you wnt to switch chanel?

Comment: That was just a quick example.  And you may need to get adapters to covert from RCA to 1/4" audio sockets.  A mixer will do what the name implies - it will "mix" all the inputs into one output (some mixers you can enable/disable channels, and on all of them you can adjust the volume of the channel).  If you know someone who does live musical performances they could be a great source of information.